# Why does it say 'Unable to find news title'?

Tags: html, python-3.x

##For my project, I am required to provide the latest news in my GUI. However, when I try scraping the headline from the source, it says no headline can be found. Is there something wrong with my coding?

```
#Defining the news source URL to extract information:
space_news = 'https://spacenews.com/'

##Back-end functionality for 'SpaceNews' button:
#Get the link to the web page from the server using the URL for
#spaceNews from above
space_news_page = urlopen(space_news)

# Extract the web page's content as a Unicode string
html_code = space_news_page.read().decode('UTF-8')

# close the connection to the web server
space_news_page.close()

#Finding the latest news from this source (mega menu content)
def space_news_headline():
    start_marker = '<h1><a href="https://spacenews.com/nasa-requests-24-8-billion-in-2022- 
    proposes-to-cancel-sofia-again/">'
    end_marker = '</a></h1>'
    start_position = html_code.find(start_marker)
    end_position = html_code.find(end_marker)
    if start_position == -1 or end_position == -1:
        print('Error: Unable to find news title')
    else:
        print('\n' + html_code[start_position + len(start_marker) : end_position].upper())

space_news_headline()
```

Comment: Is `space_q` supposed to be `space_news`?

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm it runs fine for me after that fix and putting the url all on one line.  What are the values of start_position and end_position?

Comment: I am required to show the most recent news in my GUI, meaning my interface should automatically update when the news source has updated with the latest news, the mega menu content one. So I am not really sure if my start_position and end_position should be the ones that I mentioned above. Do you know which part I should scrape for my interface to be updated with the latest news?

Comment: looks like all of the article headlines are contained in `<div class="article-content">`  so you just iterate through all of those until you have no more and retrieve the headlines out like you are now.